# Increase speed of the getfollowers function - Instagram API - By LevPasha

Tags: web-scraping, python-requests, python-multiprocessing, instagram-api, concurrent.futures

```
from InstagramAPI import InstagramAPI
import time
def getTotalFollowers(user_id):
   followers = []
   next_max_id = True
   while next_max_id:
      if next_max_id is True:
         next_max_id = ''
      _ = api.getUserFollowers(user_id, maxid=next_max_id)
      followers.extend(api.LastJson.get('users', []))
      next_max_id = api.LastJson.get('next_max_id', '')
   return followers


if __name__ == "__main__":
   #please enter your instagram username and password
   api = InstagramAPI("username","password")
   api.login()
   user_id = 6839180758
   start_time=time.time()
   followers = api.getTotalFollowers(user_id)
   print('Number of followers:', len(followers))
   print("Follower details are : "+str(followers))
   print("\n\nTotal time required : "+str(float(time.time())-float(start_time)))
```

When I try to execute this code I get total **processing time around 3 sec for 274 followers**

Can anybody apply **multiprocessing** to it so that this code can be executed fast. About **1 sec for 274 followers**

By using any of these-

- Multiprocessing
- asyncio module
- PoolExecuter

**I just want the code to executed fast you can do anything with it.**

Ps. i am new to python

Github link for above code - https://github.com/LevPasha/Instagram-API-python/blob/master/examples/user_followers.py

Answer (score 0):

```
import threading
import numpy as np
di=dict()
def getTotalFollowers(*user_ids):
    for user_id in user_ids:
       followers = []
       next_max_id = True
        while next_max_id:
          if next_max_id is True:
            next_max_id = ''
            _ = api.getUserFollowers(user_id, maxid=next_max_id)
            followers.extend(api.LastJson.get('users', []))
            next_max_id = api.LastJson.get('next_max_id', '')
        di[user_id]=followers


threads =[]
user_id=[user_id1,user_id2,...]
chunks = [i.tolist() for i in np.array_split(links, 10) if i.size>0] #10 threads
for lst in chunks:
    threads.append(threading.Thread(target=getTotalFollowers, args=(lst)))

for x in threads:
   x.start()
for x in threads:
    x.join()
print(di)
```

this will create 10 threads, which you can control the amount while creating `chunks`

Comment: Thanks , But i was looking for another answer...I have to track just one userid and increase processsing speed of finding followers of that particular account. That means a user has 300 followers on instagram...so getting his followers would require the program 3 sec...That means if someone has 5 million followers that would require a lot of time...I want to reduce that .